# How to edit an EPS with GIMP or Inkscape

Tags: vector, gimp, inkscape, eps

Newbie here. I wanted to design a wallpaper, (I was starting with a 1280x1024 size), so I downloaded this graphic from freepik [ see link below ] but I cannot figure out how to edit it.

First I loaded it into GIMP using ghostscript but the EPS file came out tiny

And then I tried to load it through Inkscape, but it either came out tiny like above or lost quality (pixelated)

(gimp on the left; zoomed in inkscape on the right)

[image]

I've tried a bunch of different things, but I don't exactly know what I'm doing...

I want to be able to edit the background/background colors (which seems like it should be transparent) and edit and/or remove the text. The lines of the bubbles have a bit of transparency to them so I want to be able to see the background through it if possible.

I've tried "ungrouping" the layers, but I am unsure if that even did anything.

Please explain what program I should be using, where I may be going wrong, and a step by step to fix this.

EDIT: 
When I attempted to specify the resolution/size (tested at 1000) in gimp, it was bigger - but pixelated...

[image]

Comment: It might help if you were to share the EPS file so that it can be checked.

Comment: the file can be found here: http://www.freepik.com/free-vector/colored-bubbles_1063923.htm  All I did was unzip the file which contained an EPS and a JPG (besides licensing info)

Comment: I can't get it to work either. Both Inkscape and GIMP only seem to open the low res thumbnail image.  It would be easy enough to recreate this yourself in Inkscape.

Comment: Any tips on how I would go about recreating it? And which would be better, inkscape or gimp?

Comment: The newest Inkscape has a gradient mesh which you could use to colour the outside of the bubble, and you can fill the mesh with semi-transparent colours. The inside white area could be made using an ellipse filled white, applying a blur, and reducing it's opacity.

Answer (score 3):

When you import an EPS in Gimp you can specify a size:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set a higher resolution when opening your EPS file, like 300DPI. Gimp likes to open EPS at 100DPI, not sure why. And if the image appears cut-off like what you showed above, increase the image res to way up like 5,000 x 5,000 to see the entire image.

I just did this and all the "pixels" are gone!

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me.
Try adding an alpha channel by right clicking on your layer.
You'll be able to edit then.